# View specific Repository interface for Database Views?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with a lot of Oracle Views at the moment using Spring Data JPA, and feel that CrudRepository offers too many methods that I don't want to expose. The reasoning is I just need the select methods

Has anyone written a view specific repository interface just exposing the retrieve methods?

Comment: use the Repository Interface an write your own methods :-)

Comment: yes - that's what I was thinking - I was just gauging whether people are using this approach, or another approach

Comment: then I will add it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Service layer between the Repository and your Business logic.

So you can only expose the methods you want to.

For testing a Service layer is nice, since you can Inject an Service stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own interface extending Repository and put methods you want to expose in it.

See [Fine-tuning repository definition](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning).